# How do i execute a query using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class ?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my code in zend. Im trying in the function getALaCarte() to execute a query and to return it as an array. but the result of the var_dump($smth) is empty. Why ?

```
<?php

namespace Application\Model\DbTable;

use Application\Model\Interfaces\ActiveEntity;

class Categories extends \Zend_Db_Table_Abstract implements ActiveEntity
{
    protected $_name     = 'categories';
    protected $_primary  = 'id';
    protected $_rowClass = 'Application\Model\Object\Category';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'xml' => array(
            'columns'       => 'xml_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Application\Model\DbTable\ProductXml',
            'refColumns'    => 'id',
        ),
    );    

    /**
     * Returns params for Zend_Db_Table_Select for fetching active categories.
     *
     * @return Zend_Db_Table_Select
     */
    public function getActiveParams()
    {
        return $this->select()->where('`is_active` = 1');
    } 

    public function getALaCarte(){

        $db = new Zend_Db_Table_Select('categories');
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * from categories c inner join xml_products x on x.id = c.xml_id where is_alacarte = '1'");
        var_dump($stmt);
        exit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you try to execute `SELECT * from categories c inner join xml_products x on x.id = c.xml_id where is_alacarte = '1'` in MySQL and make sure that the result isn't empty?

Comment: yes , and it is not empty. The query is working i'm getting the wanted results

Comment: for some reason the problem is with $db = new Zend_Db_Table_Select('categories'); this line

Comment: Are you sure that the `$db` is actually making a connection to the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * from categories c inner join xml_products x on x.id = c.xml_id where is_alacarte = '1'");
$select = $db->query($stmt);
$result = $select->execute();
var_dump($result);
```